# How can I manually remove a joomla 2.5 extension?

Tags: joomla, version, joomla2.5, uninstallation, joomla-extensions

I accidentally installed a more recent component of J2XML designed for Joomla 3 into my J2.5 site... and now I have no idea how to remove it. The only Admin page that works is the main Admin page... all the other admin pages are blank... I'm assuming it's logging the error somewhere, but I have no idea where that would be.

Can I manually remove the extension/module? What database tables should i remove?

I have already removed the folder of files, but I'm not familiar enough with the Joomla db structure to know what damage has been caused.

And in this case, backups have failed me.

Answer (score 1):

you should able to look at _components table and remove J2XML entry so it doesn't show in administrator panel

Comment: Thanks. Yeah... i looked and didn't find it but I'll look again.